# When using avfoundation - crop visible portion of captured image represented in display layer

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I am using [PBJVision](https://github.com/piemonte/PBJVision) library to capture images.

Under the hood it is using AVFoundation.

I set up the camera to use the following options

```
    PBJVision *camera = [[PBJVision alloc] init];
    self.camera = camera;
    self.camera.delegate = self;
    [self.camera setCameraMode:PBJCameraModePhoto];
    [self.camera setCameraDevice:PBJCameraDeviceFront];
    [self.camera setCameraOrientation:PBJCameraOrientationPortrait];
    [self.camera setFocusMode:PBJFocusModeAutoFocus];
    [self.camera setPresentationFrame:self.previewView.frame];
    [self.camera previewLayer].frame = self.previewView.bounds;

    [self.camera previewLayer].videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;

    [self.previewView.layer addSublayer:[self.camera previewLayer]];
```

because the preview layer gravity is set as `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill` the captured image isn't identical to the previewed image.

How can I crop it according to the video gravity?

Answer (score 2):

Based on Erica Sadun's excellent Cookbook, adding the code below to your view controller will allow you to do
    `UIImage *newImage = [self.applyAspectFillImage: image InRect: self.previewView.bounds];`

You can obtain the maximum image size by using the smaller edge (width or height) of the original photo image to size your destination rectangle.

```
CGFloat scaleW = image.size.width / previewView.bounds.size.width;
CGRect destRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, preview.bounds.size.height * scaleW);
UIImage *newImage = [self.applyAspectFillImage: image InRect: destRect];
```

The code:

```
CGRect CGRectCenteredInRect(CGRect rect, CGRect mainRect)
{
    CGFloat xOffset = CGRectGetMidX(mainRect)-CGRectGetMidX(rect);
    CGFloat yOffset = CGRectGetMidY(mainRect)-CGRectGetMidY(rect);
    return CGRectOffset(rect, xOffset, yOffset);
}


// Calculate the destination scale for filling
CGFloat CGAspectScaleFill(CGSize sourceSize, CGRect destRect)
{
    CGSize destSize = destRect.size;
    CGFloat scaleW = destSize.width / sourceSize.width;
    CGFloat scaleH = destSize.height / sourceSize.height;
    return MAX(scaleW, scaleH);
}


CGRect CGRectAspectFillRect(CGSize sourceSize, CGRect destRect)
{
    CGSize destSize = destRect.size;
    CGFloat destScale = CGAspectScaleFill(sourceSize, destRect);
    CGFloat newWidth = sourceSize.width * destScale;
    CGFloat newHeight = sourceSize.height * destScale;
    CGFloat dWidth = ((destSize.width - newWidth) / 2.0f);
    CGFloat dHeight = ((destSize.height - newHeight) / 2.0f);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake (dWidth, dHeight, newWidth, newHeight);
    return rect;
}



- (UIImage *) applyAspectFillImage: (UIImage *) image InRect: (CGRect) bounds
{
    CGRect destRect;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size);
    CGRect rect = CGRectAspectFillRect(image.size, bounds);
    destRect = CGRectCenteredInRect(rect, bounds);

    [image drawInRect: destRect];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;

}
```

Comment: How do I use this assuming I have a method that is called by the delegate:

-(void)vision:(PBJVision *)vision capturedPhoto:(NSDictionary *)photoDict error:(NSError *)error
{
    UIImage *image = [photoDict objectForKey:PBJVisionPhotoImageKey];
    if (image)
    {
       // crop the image according to the preview layer
    }
}

Comment: sorry about the bad indentation

Comment: Exactly. Erica has the method as a Category on UIImage, where it makes more sense. I did not want to complicate the answer with that.

Comment: Assuming that you added the method to your ViewController, `UIImage *newImage = [self.applyAspectFillImage: image InRect: self.previewView.bounds];`

Comment: will that return a full resolution image cropped according to the aspect ration and the contentmode or will it be cropped to the size of the view (the latter isn't wanted :) Want the full sized cropped correctly). Can you link the library?

Comment: It should do exactly the same thing that the previewLayer does. Have you tried it?

Comment: What are the size of the photo and the size of the preview?

Comment: preview layer size is limitied to screen size - image size is the one returned by avfoundation camera - 8MP on iphone 5s

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45823/discussion-between-user3071962-and-avner-barr)

Comment: I added an example on how to maintain the original photo resolution.  Can you please update my response?

Comment: I was able to produce a "print" screen of the image with the correct ratio - but the problem is that it was with the resolution of the screen and not the resolution of the image - which was much larger... I am still looking for a solution to that

Comment: Did you see my code fragment in the answer on how to size the destination rectangle to get the full resolution? The fragment assumes "portrait" orientation. Again, if you could provide sample preview image bounds I could verify it on paper.